# swift - access JSON data

Tags: json, swift

I'am parsing JSON data from an API. As seen below, I can access cars struct. But I couldn't find a way to access "dealer".

JSON Data:

```
return value = {
                  "total_count": 1, 
                  "cars": [{
                               "brand": "toyota",
                               "color": "black"
                  }],
                  "dealers": {"dealer_id": 60,
                            "dealer_location": "UK"}
                  }
}
```

TableViewController:

```
var carList: [JSON]? = []

func loadData(){
            let url = "http://example.com"
            Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
                if (json != nil){
                    var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                    if let data = jsonObj["cars"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                        self.car = data
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
 }
```

TableViewCell:

```
var cars:JSON?{
        didSet{
            self.setupCarData()
        }
}

func setupCarData(){
        self.brandLabel.text = self.cars?["brand"].string
}
```

I tried, but I only got NIL.

```
self.dealerIDLabel.text = self.cars?["dealer"][dealer_id].string
```

Comment: dealers is not in cars

Comment: I try to display bot cars and dealers data in my tableviewcell. How I am going to pass bot cars and dealers data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Whats the relationship between cars and dealers? What would a single cell display?

Comment: I am getting the JSON Data above from an api link. A cell will display, car brand and available dealer info.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
self.dealerIDLabel.text = jsonObj["dealers"]["dealer_id"].string
```